# Skip Authorization when request is not authenticated ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

My authorization handler for an authorization requirement is being executed even when the request does not contain a JWT token.

I think it's nonsense. Did I something wrong? or it's expected and should be handled manually?

Configuration:

```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Puls.Cloud.Services.Account.API v1"));
    }

    app.UseProblemDetails();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
    });

    app.UseSwagger();
```

DI:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encryptionKey),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
        x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
        };
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
         options.AddPolicy(RequirePermissionAttribute.RequirePermissionPolicyName, policyBuilder =>
         {
             policyBuilder.Requirements.Add(new RequirePermissionAuthorizationRequirement());
             policyBuilder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
         });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the controller too?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.UseEndpoints() there is

> endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();

as it clear this will force *DefaultPolicy* to your Controllers.

you should do one of these options:

**Option 1**:Handle it with *[AllowAnonymous]* attribute

**Option 2**:Handle it with Custom *AuthorizationHandler*

Please check these links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-custom-iauthorizationpolicyprovider

Comment: I need authorization for my endpoints. my problem is: check authorization just for authenticated requests.

Comment: @M.Khooryani as i know , when you are using .RequireAuthorization() , every requests that is matched with your routing ( all of requests in your case ) needs to be Authorized . so you should handle it manually . for example you can use .Map custom middleware between Authentication and Authorization middleware to check if token presented or not. i think this is right